# jQuery how prevent event inside event function

Tags: jquery, html-table, onchange

I have a table and when a user change a ID in a row I have to relocate row to new position based on this new ID.

So I create a change function to manage this, but inside my code I trigger the change again when moving rows.

There is a way to not trigger change when moving, or I have to trigger change in a different way?

Any ideas?

HTML CODE:

```
<table id='eap'>
    <tr><th>ID</th><th>INFO1</th><th>INFO2</th></tr>
    <tr><td><input name="ID1" value='1'/></td><td>1.1</td><td>1.2</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input name="ID2" value='2'/></td><td>2.1</td><td>2.2</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input name="ID3" value='3'/></td><td>3.1</td><td>3.2</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input name="ID4" value='4'/></td><td>4.1</td><td>4.2</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input name="ID5" value='5'/></td><td>5.1</td><td>5.2</td></tr>
</table>
```

JQUERY CODE:

```
$('#eap tbody tr input[name^="ID"]').change(function () {
    alert('start');

    //changed row
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr');

    //New ID
    var $newID = this.value;

    //Loop all in search for the correct ID position
    $('#eap tr input[name^="ID"]').each(function (i){
        if ( (parseInt($newID) <= parseInt($(this).val())) && $row.index() != $(this).closest('tr').index() ){
            //found position
            $newrow = $(this).closest('tr');

            //move row
            //this trigger change again
            $($newrow).before($($row));

            return false;
        }
    });

    //put id in order
    $id=1;
    $('#eap tr input[name^="ID"]').each(function (i){           
        $(this).val($id);
        $id++;                          
    });        
});
```

[Demo on JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pedsann/yLc5s/)

Comment: In your jsfiddle with firefox change only triggers once (the alert only shows once)

Comment: You are right. The problem occurs on Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood you. I would use the [`blur`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) event rather than the [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event.

```
$('#eap tbody tr input[name^="ID"]').blur(function () {
...
```

Comment: But I must wait user enter the complete ID. With keyup, if the ID is 100, when user digit 1 the row will change, don't?

Comment: Yes, blur is the best option.